# The word word for a weak intention?

Tags: word-choice

How is called the word that means to have an intention or wish so weak that he/she  decides not to do something. What I remember is that this word it seems have common roots with the word *volition* and it is formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of words come to mind.  **irresolute** if the intention is never fully established because the person is hesitant or uncertain of what course to take, or **vacillating** if the person keeps going back and forth between options. There is also, of course, **weak-willed**.

Answer (score 0):

velleity

1. volition in its weakest form.
2. a mere wish, unaccompanied by an effort to obtain it.